# requireJS ignores my paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to get `requireJS` to help me load in some dependencies for my backbone.js-based application. My files are in the `/some/path` directory, but require.js seems to completely ignore this and instead tries to load them without the `baseUrl` prefix.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my snippet:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/some/path"
});

require(myArrayWithFiles, callback() { //... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edith says:** I'm not sure anymore if this really works in requirejs, at least it should work like this :)

The problem here is that you configured a require instance you don't use in your call. It should look like this:

```js
var myRequire = require.config({
    baseUrl: "/some/path"
});

myRequire(myArrayWithFiles, callback() { //... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you might need a trailing '/' on your path.

What does `myArrayWithFiles` evaluate to?